# Compiling module that involves 'sys_mount' calls

Tags: c, include, linux-kernel, mount

I'm developing a module for linux and I need to mount a .iso file.

I have read and found that there is a function called sys_mount that calls the linux's mount programm and does all that stuff.

The problem is that when I'm trying to compile it shows a warning that says: '"sys_mount" [/home/.../example.ko] undefined!' and then when I try "insmod example.ko" it says that "insmod: error inserting 'example.ko': -1 Unkown symbol in module".

Does anyone know what should I do to compile it?
Do I need to include something that is missing?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 3):

[`sys_mount`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/fs/namespace.c#L2490) is what a user program invokes via the `mount` syscall. It performs argument validation and copying before calling [`do_mount`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/fs/namespace.c#L2288), which does the bulk of the job. From within the kernel, call `do_mount` directly. This `sys_foo`/`do_foo` separation is a common convention for Linux syscall implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesnt solves my problem.
What I want to know is how I compile my module that calls sys_mount() or what is the way of doing mount from a linux device driver?

Comment: You call `do_mount`. If something doesn't work, post at least your `Kbuild`, and copy-paste the full error messages.